# The head node in a linked list

Tags: c++, data-structures

The following naive code implements a linked list, without printing all the elements in the main function, everything would be fine. However, the `LinkedList::printll` function will trigger a set fault(Gcc 5.3.0), the problem is related to the appropriate handling of the head node I suppose...

So, is there any way to make this code work with least modification of the `printll` function?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Node{
  int value;
  Node* next;
};

struct LinkedList{
  Node* head= NULL ; 
  void append(int);
  void printll();
};

void LinkedList::append(int data){
  Node* cur = head;
  Node* tmp = new Node;
  tmp->value = data;
  tmp->next = NULL;

    if(!cur){
        cur = tmp;                       // cur-> head
    }
    else{
       while(cur->next != NULL){
       cur = cur->next;
       }
       cur->next = tmp;
    }
    std::cout<<cur->value<<std::endl;    // cur-> temp
  delete tmp;                            // comment out
}

void LinkedList::printll(){ 
     Node* cur = head;
        while(cur->next != NULL){        //
        std::cout<<cur->value<<std::endl;
        cur = cur->next;
        }
}


int main(){
  LinkedList LL;
  LL.append(5);
  LL.append(6);
  LL.append(7);
  LL.printll();  // --without this, the program is fine
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some bugs in `append`:

```
if(!cur){
    cur = tmp;
}
```

This only assigns to the local copy. I assume you are trying to set `head` here, so do that: `head = tmp;`. Note that in this case, you can't print `cur`, since you haven't set it. You could print `tmp->value` though.

Then:

```
delete tmp;
```

You only just created it and assigned it into place - why are you deleting it? You *know* that there is still a pointer to it. Only `delete` it when you come to clean up the list when you are done with it (which you don't do at all at the moment).

Other than that, your `printll` won't print the last element - think about when it will stop:

```
A -> B -> C -> NULL
```

It will stop on node `C`, but never print `C`'s value. You can just replace:

```
while(cur->next != NULL){
```

with

```
while(cur != nullptr){
```

(Also, I don't like [`endl`](http://chris-sharpe.blogspot.co.uk/2016/02/why-you-shouldnt-use-stdendl.html)).

[See here for these changes running](http://ideone.com/xhGwq0):

```
#include <iostream>

struct Node{
    int value;
    Node* next;
};

struct LinkedList{
    Node* head = nullptr ; 
    void append(int);
    void printll();
};

void LinkedList::append(int data){
    Node* cur = head;
    Node* tmp = new Node;
    tmp->value = data;
    tmp->next = nullptr;

    if(!cur){
        head = tmp;
    }
    else{
        while(cur->next != nullptr){
            cur = cur->next;
        }
        cur->next = tmp;
    }
}

void LinkedList::printll(){ 
    Node* cur = head;
    while(cur != nullptr){
        std::cout << cur->value << '\n';
        cur = cur->next;
    }
}


int main(){
    LinkedList LL;
    LL.append(5);
    LL.append(6);
    LL.append(7);
    LL.printll();
}
```

Comment: As @BoBTFish says, you must remove `delete tmp;` from you code (why are you `delete` a `node` you have just added it to `List`?), and change your `while` loop in `printll`, suggestion: `while (cur)`

Comment: I changed all that suggested by @BoBTFish, and I am using GCC 5.3.0 to compile, however, it still segfault.. the problem happens at "cur->next" I guess

Comment: @lorniper When I made the changes I suggested, I was able to compile and run properly. Can you post your exact code that is still segfaulting?

Comment: @lorniper You still try to print `cur->value` even though you have changed it to set `head` directly.

Answer (score 0):

1.you cann't

```
delete tmp;
```

cause tmp is a pointer, when you run delete tmp, you delete the object.

2.the print function should like this:

```
void LinkedList::printll(){
     Node* cur = head;
        while(cur->next != NULL){        // -> problems is here
        std::cout<<cur->value<<std::endl;
        cur = cur->next;
        }
        std::cout<<cur->value<<std::endl;
}
```